# Friedman's test in SPSS gives different results from R and python

Tags: python, r, spss

I have a repeated measurement of n=452 participants. The Friedman test of SPSS gives df=2, chi-square 36.970 whereas below is the output of R and python. I cannot explain this difference for chi-square value (30 from R and python vs 36 from SPSS) although it is not too much. Can anyone help me understand this?

```
#Friedman rank sum test in R        
friedman.test(data.matrix(x))
data:  data.matrix(x)
Friedman chi-squared = 30.389, df = 2, p-value = 2.518e-07

#----------------------------------------------

#Friedman Test in python
friedmanchisquare(x1, x2, x3)

FriedmanchisquareResult(statistic=30.38907395069963, pvalue=2.5182360483490374e-07)
```

SPSS output
[image]

Comment: How rounding up 30 woud be 36 for chi-square?

Comment: oh sorry i missed the spss, i was referring to python and r. i am not familiar with spss, you got to check how they calculate it...

Answer (score 1):

This was posted also in Cross Validated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467977/friedmans-test-in-spss-gives-different-results-from-r-and-python/468930?noredirect=1#comment873244_468930). The issue was "fuzz" in the input data that was treated differently by the packages.